# android spannable edititext with cursor manipulation

Tags: android, spannablestring

I am trying to implement code highlighting using spanned text and html.fromhtml() function in an edittext than implements text watcher.
The problem occurs when i try to manipulate cursor for custom brackets, the app crashes due to some spannable string setspan error.
How do i use spannable code highlighting and set cursor position adjusting according to the spanned text.

Edit:

The function:

```
 Spanned matchtext(String s)
{
    //Pattern p =Pattern.compile(check[0]);

    String a=s;
    for(int i=0;i<Constants.keyWords.length;i++) {
        a = a.replaceAll(Constants.keyWords[i], "<font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + Constants.keyWords[i] + "</font>");
        //a = s.replaceAll(";", "<font color=\"#c5c5c5\">" + ";" + "</font>");
    }
    Spanned ab = Html.fromHtml(a);
    return ab;

}
```

And the function call:

```
mCodeEditText.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
bs = matchtext(s.toString());
mCodeEditText.setText(bs);
mCodeEditText.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Edit 2:

This is my new implementation, I just can't get the highlighting to work.

```
Spannable matchtext(String s, int pos) {

    Spannable abc = new SpannableString(s);
    for (int i = 0; i < Constants.keyWords.length; i++) {
        if (pos - Constants.keyWords[i].length() >= 0) {
            int j = s.indexOf(Constants.keyWords[i]);
            if (j != -1) {
                if ((s.subSequence(j, pos)).equals(Constants.keyWords[i]))
                    abc.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), j, pos, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            }
        }
    }
    return abc;

}
```

Comment: Hi Aakash, please add relevant code into your question so people can see the details.

Comment: @gitsitgo I have added the code, please take a look.

Comment: `Html#fromHtml` is not meant for such purpose, use `Spannable#setSpan` instead

Comment: @pskink I tried that, check the edit.

Comment: Was setSpan called?  Did you debug your code?

Comment: I got it to work. Forgot to set the returned value to the edittext. Thanks a lot.